# Checkbox not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Before this is marked as duplicate I have searched and none of the answers seems to work for me.

My checkbox isn't working when changed, clicked, checked it whatever.

This is my component

```
class Checkbox extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {checked: false}
    this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
  }
  this.handleCheck(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      checked: e.target.checked
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.handleChecked}
    );
  }
}
```

Any reason why it shouldn't work?

Comment: e.preventDefault() fault? :) remove it!

Comment: you reference `this.handleChecked` in the `onChange`, but your method is named `handleCheck`

Comment: @Hamms, good catch!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { checked: false }
    this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
  }

  handleCheck(e){
   this.setState({
    checked: e.target.checked
   })
 }
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id ="checkbox_id"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={this.state.checked}
        onChange={this.handleCheck}
      />
      <label htmlFor="checkbox_id"></label>
    </div>
   );
}
}

render(<Checkbox />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/50rox77w8x)

**Issues**

- Method should be initialised as `handleCheck(e)` not `this.handleCheck(e)`
- There shouldn't be `e.preventDefault()`
- `onChange={this.handleCheck}`
- As you are using [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/), you need to add an `id` in `input` and a label for this id.

Comment: It works. But when I load my materialize css stylesheet it stops working. Any knowledge about that?

Comment: I think your css stylesheet override the style so that it doesn't look like checked. Can you share your css file?

Comment: I'm not loading any custom css. I'm using materialize css framework

Comment: In this case, you need a checkbox id and a label which is styled by materialise css. See my update.

Comment: I've figured it out. It's because of a class `.input-field` it's not supposed to be there

Comment: Great! my problem was I had to put a stopPropagation on my checkbox, and added also a preventDefault that was preventing it to set the checked property properly. I removed the preventDefault and it worked.